# Personal form validation in js, with warning messages

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to create personal form with submit button. After press submit button I want to get warning message e.g. "This field should contain only capital and lower letters". If the field is fill correct go forward.

I create object named `validationRules={}`, where I use `pattern:` as Regex code, `required:` true (field is required)or false (field isn't required), and `error:` 'warning message'.Fields named `street` and `streetNo` aren't required.

I am working on, how to get access to validationRules to every 'error: '....'.
I create `var get_error` to get access to `erorr:`'......', but isn't working.
  
`var get_error = validationRules.firstName.error
    errors.forEach(function(error) {
      document.getElementById('warning_msg').innerHTML = get_error;
    })`

[Here is code based](https://jsbin.com/cuzupegeko/edit?html,js,output)

I will be appreciated to get some hints.

Comment: You can start by updating `document.getElementById('warning_msg').innerHTML += error.error + "<br/>"`;.

Comment: another thing is you have to pause submit action, while you enter your validation function and after validate all pass then keep submit.
"submit" button will auto refresh your browser.

Answer (score 2):

I created something that can help you with that, i know the js code might seem a lot but you can use it and gone on from there, Here is the a link to my sample validation [test](https://jsbin.com/wisatuh/edit?html,js,output)

```
function Validation( items ) {
    'use strict';
    this.items  = items || {};
    this.errors = {};
    this.data = {};
    this.success = false;
}

Validation.prototype.check = function( form ) {
    'use strict';
    for ( var elem in (this.items) ) {
        if ( {}.hasOwnProperty.call(this.items, elem) ) {
            var rules = this.items[elem];
            var formElement = form[elem];
            // Is it an instance of radionodelist or not
            // As in is a radio or checkbox
            if ( 'tagName' in formElement ) {
                switch ( formElement.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
                    case 'select':
                        this.validateSelect( elem, rules, formElement, form, this.items );
                        break;
                    case 'input':
                    case 'textarea':
                    default:
                        this.validateInput( elem, rules, formElement, form, this.items );
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                var firstNode = formElement[0]; // FormElement contains a RadioNodeList Object
                switch ( firstNode.getAttribute('type').toLowerCase() ) {
                    case 'radio':
                        this.validateRadio( elem, rules, formElement, form, this.items );
                        break;
                    case 'checkbox':
                        this.validateCheckBox( elem, rules, formElement, form, this.items );
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ( isEmpty(this.errors) ) {
        this.success = true;
    }

    return this;
};

// Validate provided value, if any
Validation.prototype.validateValue = function( value, elem, rules, form, items ) {
    'use strict';
    var error = false;

    if ( 'required' in rules ) {
        if ( value.length === 0 ) {
            this.errors[elem] = rules['name'] + ' is required';
            error = true;
        }
    }

    if ( (value.length !== 0) && !(error) ) {
        if ( 'min' in rules ) {
            if ( rules['expected'].toLowerCase() === 'integer' ) {
                // Check if a valid number or integer is provided
                if ( isNaN(Number(value)) ) {
                    this.errors[elem] = rules['name'] + ' is not a valid number';
                    error = true;
                }
            }

            if ( !(error) ) {
                if ( this.checkMin(value, rules['min'], rules['expected']) ) {
                    this.errors[elem] = this.getMinMessage( 
                            rules['name'], rules['min'], rules['expected'] 
                    );
                    error = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ( (value.length !== 0) && !(error) ) {
        if ( 'max' in rules ) {
            if ( rules['expected'].toLowerCase() === 'integer' ) {
                // Check if a valid number or integer is provided
                if ( isNaN(Number(value)) ) {
                    this.errors[elem] = rules['name'] + ' is not a valid number';
                    error = true;
                }
            }

            if ( !(error) ) {
                if ( this.checkMax(value, rules['max'], rules['expected']) ) {
                    this.errors[elem] = this.getMaxMessage( 
                            rules['name'], rules['max'], rules['expected'] 
                    );
                    error = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ( (value.length !== 0) && !(error) ) {
        if ( 'matches' in rules ) {
            var compareValue = form[rules['matches']].value;
            if ( value !== compareValue ) {
                var compareName = items[ rules['matches'] ];
                compareName = compareName['name'];
                this.errors[elem] = rules['name'] + ' does not match ' + compareName;
                error = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( (value.length !== 0) && !(error) ) {
        if ( 'email' in rules ) {
            if ( !(this.checkEmail(value)) ) {
                this.errors[elem] = rules['name'] + ' is not valid';
                error = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( (value.length !== 0) && !(error) ) {
        if ( 'date' in rules ) {
            if ( !(this.checkDate(value)) ) {
                this.errors[elem] = rules['name'] + ' is not a valid date';
                error = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( (value.length !== 0) && !(error) ) {
        if ( 'permitted' in rules ) {
            if ( value.indexOf('fakepath') !== -1 && value.indexOf('\\') !== -1 ) {
                value = value.split('\\').pop();
            } else if ( value.indexOf('fakepath') !== -1 && value.indexOf('/') !== -1 ) {
                value = value.split('/').pop();
            }

            var permitted = rules['permitted'];
            var checkValue = value.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if ( permitted.indexOf(checkValue) === -1 ) {
                this.errors[elem] = rules['name'] + ' is not permitted';
                error = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( (value.length !== 0) && !(error) ) {
        if ( 'pattern' in rules ) {
            var regex = rules['pattern'];
            if ( !(regex.test(value)) ) {
                this.errors[elem] = rules['name'] + ' is not in the required format';
                error = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Finally, if no error add to data collection
    if ( !(error) ) {
        this.data[elem] = value;
    }
};

// Validate Select Menu
Validation.prototype.validateSelect = function( elem, rules, formElement, form, items ) {
    'use strict';
    var value = '';
    if ( formElement.hasAttribute('multiple') ) {
        value = [];
        for ( var i = 0, len = formElement.options.length; i < len; i += 1 ) {
            if ( formElement.options[i].selected ) {
                value.push( trim(formElement.options[i].value) );
            }
        }
    } else {
        value = trim( formElement.value );
    }

    this.validateValue( value, elem, rules, form, items );
}; 

// Validate Textarea or Input of type text, password, 
// date, search, email etc 
Validation.prototype.validateInput = function( elem, rules, formElement, form, items ) {
    'use strict';
    var value = '';

    if ( formElement.hasAttribute('type') ) {
        if ( formElement.getAttribute('type').toLowerCase() === 'password' ) {
            value = formElement.value;
        } else {
            value = trim( formElement.value );
        }
    } else {
        // Textarea value
        value = trim( formElement.value );
    }  


    this.validateValue( value, elem, rules, form, items );
};

// Validate Radio Buttons
Validation.prototype.validateRadio = function( elem, rules, nodeList, form, items ) {
    'use strict';
    var value = '';
    for ( var i = 0, len = nodeList.length; i < len; i += 1 ) {
        if ( nodeList[i].checked ) {
            value = trim( nodeList[i].value );
            break;
        }
    }

    this.validateValue( value, elem, rules, form, items );
};

// Validate Checkboxes
Validation.prototype.validateCheckBox = function( elem, rules, nodeList, form, items ) {
    'use strict';
    var values = [];
    for ( var i = 0, len = nodeList.length; i < len; i += 1 ) {
        if ( nodeList[i].checked ) {
            values.push( trim(nodeList[i].value) );
        }
    }

    this.validateValue( values, elem, rules, form, items );
};

Validation.prototype.getMinMessage = function( name, minValue, expected ) {
    'use strict';
    expected = expected || '';
    switch ( expected.toLowerCase() ) {
        case 'integer':
            return name + ' cannot be less than ' + minValue;
            break;
        case 'string':
            return name + ' must be a minimum of ' + minValue + ' characters';
            break;
        default:
            return 'You must select at least ' + minValue + ' ' + name;
            break;
    }
};

Validation.prototype.getMaxMessage = function( name, maxValue, expected ) {
    'use strict';
    expected = expected || '';
    switch ( expected.toLowerCase() ) {
        case 'integer':
            return name + ' cannot be greater than ' + maxValue;
            break;
        case 'string':
            return name + ' must be a maximum of ' + maxValue + ' characters';
            break;
        default:
            return 'You must select a maximum of ' + maxValue + ' ' + name;
            break;
    }
};

// Check Minimum value
Validation.prototype.checkMin = function( value, minValue, expected ) {
    'use strict';
    expected = expected || '';
    switch ( expected.toLowerCase() ) {
        case 'integer':
            return Number(value) < minValue;
            break;
        case 'string':
            return String(value).length < minValue;
            break;
        default:
            return value.length < minValue;
            break;
    }
};

// Check Maximum value
Validation.prototype.checkMax = function( value, maxValue, expected ) {
    'use strict';
    expected = expected || '';
    switch ( expected.toLowerCase() ) {
        case 'integer':
            return Number(value) > maxValue;
            break;
        case 'string':
            return String(value).length > maxValue;
            break;
        default:
            return value.length > maxValue;
            break;
    }
};

// Check email value
Validation.prototype.checkDate = function( value ) {
    'use strict';
    var date = new Date( value );
    return ( isNaN(date.getDate()) ) ? false : true;
};

// Check email value
Validation.prototype.checkEmail = function( value ) {
    'use strict';
    var emailRegex = /^[\w.%+\-]+@[\w.\-]+\.[A-za-z]{2,}$/;
    return emailRegex.test( value );
};

Validation.prototype.getErrors = function() {
    'use strict';
    return this.errors;
};

Validation.prototype.getData = function() {
    'use strict';
    return this.data;
};

Validation.prototype.passed = function() {
    'use strict';
    return this.success;
};
```